# Panorama Tracker add-on for 2.80+

Tags: python, add-on, panoramic, vr

There used to be a panorama tracker add-on for 2.7 which allowed you to stabilise 360 degree videos. It worked really well but stopped working with Blender 2.8.
https://github.com/dfelinto/Panorama-Tracker

I had a look at porting this over but it's a bit over my head.

Is there an alternative solution for Blender 3.6 or even 2.83?